# Ver código en tiempo real en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

¿Existe alguna manera en *.NET* de ver los cambios en el código mientras está ejecutándose la aplicación en *C# (Windows Forms)*, sin necesidad de cerrar la misma, y después volver a compilarla?.

Algo así como **Hot Reload** en *HTML*, *Visual Studio Code*.

Me gustaría, que si por ejemplo muevo un botón de posición en el formulario, este cambie en la aplicación mientras esta está en funcionamiento.

Comment: de que tipo de desarrollo hablamos? es web, winform, wpf, etc

Comment: @LeandroTuttini estamos hablando de winform, disculpa que no lo aclaré.

Comment: me temo que winform no tiene ese capacidad de edicion en runtime

Comment: Coincido con @LeandroTuttini, me parece que para winforms no hay forma.

Comment: No hay forma lamentablemente.

Comment: Habria que ver si con VS2019 y Net Core 3.0 (que incluye el nuevo compilador) donde permite hacer apps de escritorio permite esto. Lamentablemente el editor visual aun esta en preview y hay que esperar un poco mas.

Answer (score 0):

Hay una característica en Visual Studio que se llama [Editar y continuar](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/debugger/edit-and-continue?view=vs-2017) que has de habilitar en las opciones del proyecto, y que solamente es posible en compilaciones y ejecución en modo depuración. Requiere pausar la ejecución (o un punto de interrupción) para poder editar el código, y hay limitaciones en cuanto a los lenguajes que se soportan y los cambios en el código permitidos. Está todo documentado en el enlace.